# Choosing an autocorrelation structure with negative correlation at last lag

Tags: correlation, autocorrelation

I have a linear model for an experiment using repeated measures.  Thus far I've used lme in R to test the model.  For this model the the latest lag is 6.  The ACFs are:

```
Lag: 1           2           3            4           5            6
ACF: 0.01076084, 0.04204100, -0.11440165, 0.01422727, -0.06761294, -0.64110161
```

Based on the design there is not any intuitive reason for the significant correlation at lag 6, rather I would have expected something like an AR1.  I'm not at all experienced in dealing with autocorrelation.  I'm trying to do two things: 1) choose an appropriate autocorrelation structure for the model. 2) understand what this correlation means interpretively.  Thank you.

Comment: How many time steps are there in your data?

Comment: There are 7 time steps

Comment: I wonder whether the last lag is really significant, then.  How did you determine its significance?

Comment: I plotted the ACF values along with the confidence interval for the correlation.  It is well beyond the confidence limit at alpha=.01.  Is there a better way to test this?

Comment: The confidence interval is a large-sample approximation.  It is way, way off for this tiny dataset.  Literally any value of the ACF for the largest lag should be considered insignificant.

Comment: Rather than just asserting that there is no intuitive reason for the result, can you please give more information on context and meaning for your data.  For example, is this monthly data, where a six-month delay would represent an inversion of seasons?

Answer (score 1):

The sample ACVF (autocovariance function) at lag $ h $ is defined as

$$
\hat{\gamma}(h) = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{t=1}^{n-h} (x_t - \bar{x}_n)(x_{t+h} - \bar{x}_n)
$$

where $ \bar{x}_n $ is the mean of the time series.

Thus, given that your time series has a total of 7 datapoints, the ACVF at lag 6 is highly sensitive to the first and last values of your time series,
and thus the reported autocorrelation should *not* be regarded as significant.